# CMake and Visual Studio 2010 and Additional Library Directories

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake, directory

How can I tell CMake that I want it to generate a Visual Studio 2010 solution by setting also the "Additional Library Directories" field in the "Linker" section of the Project properties?
Language is C++ and not using the .NET platform, simply I want that my project to find the stage/lib dir where Boost .lib and .dll are stored...

Obviously, I have tried with following settings but, while the field Additional include dirs for the compiler are correctly set, the Additional library dirs for the linker still remains empty...

```
unset(Boost_LIBRARIES)

find_package(Boost 1.55.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem)

if(Boost_FOUND)
   set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
   set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
   set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR stage/lib)
   include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

...

target_link_libraries(cpp-lib ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

I specify also that I want to use the dynamic version of Boost libs, that is why I set the switch USE_STATIC_LIBS to OFF for the use of the static version of Boost at the beginning of the CMakelists.txt.

This is what has been put in the Additional Dependencies field (beyond the usual .lib automatically specified there by Visual Studio):

```
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_56_0\stage\lib\boost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_56.lib
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_56_0\stage\lib\boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_56.lib
```

Beyond the wrong field in which this has been written, I would also add that the above lines are not what I want. I would like to have only the specification of the Boost .lib and .dll path, that is simply:

```
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_56_0\stage\lib\
```

I have tried by putting this last path in the Linker->General->Additional Library Directories field and all compiles fine, so I need a way to tell CMake to set the correct path (the last above) in the correct field (Linker->General->Additional Library Directories).

Tnx a lot

D.

Comment: Just discovered that this way the full path names of the Boost libraries (system, filesystem) have been put in the field Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies... But this is not what I asked to CMake through the command target_link_libraries()!!

Comment: You must set the Boost variables *before* calling find_package

Comment: @Peter I have tried what you suggested but it did not work. I still have the libraries in Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies, but not in Linker->General->Additional Library Directories

Comment: Trust CMake to generate project files that build the project.  It sounds like you're trying to accomplish something different.  Please explain WHY you want specific settings populated in the project file.

Comment: I don't want something different for the sake of, but simply because now the project generated with CMake does not link, while putting the setting I would like to it links correctly (I have tried adding the settings by hand and it works... so I would like to make CMake do as I am doing by hand...). :(

Comment: You are describing a very specific solution that you think you need, rather than your problem.  Your problem is that CMake is not linking Boost.  What you've described as being in the "Additional Dependencies" field should work fine.  Please edit your question, or start over entirely, to clearly describe the actual problem you're having, leaving out the way you think it needs to be fixed.  Be sure to include the updated CMake script which fixes the order.

Answer (score 4):

By using link_directories(), I was able to update "Additional Library Directories" field in the "Linker" section of the Project properties.

```
find_package(Boost 1.55.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem)

if(Boost_FOUND)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
    set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
    set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR stage/lib)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

    link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

endif()
```

Answer (score 1):

> ... so I need a way to tell CMake to set the correct path (the last
>   above) in the correct field (Linker->General->Additional Library
>   Directories).

CMake `link_directories` maps to VS `Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories`

Related to it, CMake `target_link_libraries` maps to VS `Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`.

Take a look at [CMake and Visual Studio](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/cmake-and-visual-studio/) which lists other CMake commands in the context of Visual Studio with an example.